# $T$ is reducible over the eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question
Let $T \in L(U)$ and $\lambda_1,...\lambda_k$ be some distinct eigenvalues of $T$ such that $T$ is reducible over the eigenspaces $E_{\lambda_1},...E_{\lambda_k}$. Show that $\lambda_1,...\lambda_k$ are all the eigenvalues of $T$. In other words, if $\lambda$ is any eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda$ is among $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$.

I think the key to this proof is that $T$ is reducible over the eigenspaces. However, $T$ is not given a dimension, and there is no geometric multiplicity given, so I'm a little lost.

Since $T$ is reducible over the eigenspaces. That means that $\dim(U)=\dim(\Sigma E_{\lambda_1} +...+E_{\lambda_k})$, I think. Also it means that $T$ can have a matrix $A$ that is a box triangular matrix, but I'm not quite sure what that would imply. Please help

Comment: I've never seen the notion of being reducible over some eigenspaces. Could you provide the definition of that notion?

Comment: A matrix is reducible if and only if it can be placed into block upper-triangular form by simultaneous row/column permutations. In addition, a matrix is reducible if and only if its associated digraph is not strongly connected. A square matrix that is not reducible is said to be irreducible.